# How to Loop Through a Large Array With the Or Function

Tags: arrays, vhdl

## Problem

I have created a simple script which scans through a number of pins that I define in the top level (`N`). If the pins are dead, they will remain high or low usually, or do something unexpected. At the moment, a single pulse is sent down each pin, with a delay of a clock cycle between them.

## My Attempt

These pulses are sent to an array named `s_pulse`. The size of this array is dynamically created upon synthesis like so:

```
<snip>
generic (N : natural);
<snip>

PulseGen : for I in 0 to N-1 generate
    begin
    FMC_IBUF : IBUFDS
   generic map (
        DIFF_TERM => TRUE,
        IOSTANDARD => "DEFAULT")
   port map (  
      O  => s_pulse (I) ,
      I => pulse_p (I) ,
      IB  => pulse_n (I) 
      );
end generate PulseGen;
```

Then I wish to send out the signal whenever there is one to a `std_logic` pin named `pulse`, this works but it doesn't work dynamically for obvious reasons like the above, but I can't figure out a way to do it:

```
if rising_edge(clk) then
    pulse <= s_pulse(0) or s_pulse(1) or s_pulse(2) or s_pulse(3)....
end if;
```

Any ideas on how I can quickly generate a large `or` function for each member of the array, or suggest some function I don't know of to make this shorter and more importantly, dynamic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the weary traveller, I found a solution:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_misc.all;
<snip>

    if rising_edge(clk) then
        pulse <= or_reduce(s_fmc);

    end if;
```

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008, while not guaranteed to be universally synthesis tool accepted includes unary logic (reduction) operators where your solution could be shown as `pulse <= or s_fmc;`, and when ambiguous in an expression the reduction could be shown as `(or s_fmc)`. These are found in the -2008 version of package std_logic_1164.

Comment: std_logic_misc is not a standard library. If your tools support VHDL-2002 you should use ieee.reduce_pack instead.

Comment: Both interesting =) took me a while to find the solution as I couldn't think of a way to easily phrase the search. Still this worked and I'll take onboard those comments for next time =)